# Parameterized "name" property in react-hook-form Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have got an application where I am creating a form page component which dynamically generates the form fields based on an array, e.g. ['firstName', 'lastName']

The problem is I get a type error when I am trying to use a variable/parameter for the "name" property of the Controller. I tried casting the parameter as FieldPath, FieldPath and a few others but to no avail.

I have managed to make a dynamic defaultValues object, but I don't know how to link each Controller based on a variable name so that it doesn't complain.

I have also tried with ...register, but same type error and I am not using native inputs, so Controller would be recommended anyway.

Here's the code and sandbox link:

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
  const inputFields = ["firstName", "lastName"];

  let formDefaultValues = {};
  inputFields.forEach((field) => {
    formDefaultValues = { [field]: "", ...formDefaultValues };
  });

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: formDefaultValues,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      {inputFields.map((x) => (
        <Controller
          key={x}
          name={x}
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <div>
              <input onChange={field.onChange} />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>Test values</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sad-night-8s0pz4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is the way you create and initialize `formDefaultValues`:

```
let formDefaultValues = {}
```

From here TypeScript infers the variable has a type of `{}` (the empty object), which has no properties, then you pass this to `useForm` as `defaultValues`, so `defaultValues` ends up having a type of `{}` as well. Finally, you create two `Controller`s using the `control` returned by that call to `useForm`. Now, if you take a look at the [props received by the `Controller` component](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/v7.43.8/src/types/controller.ts#L37) in the `react-hook-form` repo, you will find out the prop `name` should be a valid field path but, since TypeScript is inferring the type of the form object associated with the `control` and the call to `useForm` is `{}`, which has no properties and therefore no possible path, this prop `name` ends up having a type of `never` and that's the reason of why you are getting a type mismatch:

**Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.**

So, to fix this you have to hint TypeScript with the right type for the default values:

```
const formDefaultValues: Record<string, string> = inputFields.reduce(
  (pv, f) => ({ ...pv, [f]: '' }),
  {}
)
```

Let me know if that worked for you. Greetings